# Response from API is in a dictionary format

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, dictionary

I'm having an issue getting a response from an rest API into a json format with Pandas. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Token token="mytoken"',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache--url',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.someurl.com/api/path', headers=headers)
data = response.json()
```

This is my issue: Whenever I check the data type that I get in response, it is in a dictionary format, like so:

```
In[2]: type(data)
Out[2]: dict
```

Because it returns text that's in a JSON format, but it comes into my code as a dictionary, I cannot use panda's .read_json() command because it appears that it's expecting a JSON datatype. Whenever I try to do that, it returns this:

```
In[3]: pd.read_json(data)
Out[3]: ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>
```

I think the main issue is that my response returns in the form of a dictionary instead of pure JSON, and not because of the syntax within the JSON data itself, but by no means am I an expert in this subject. Let me know what you guys think.

Here's the documentation to the API I'm using:

https://documentation.joinhandshake.com/v1.0/reference#introduction

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `data = response.json()` converts the response to a python structure. That may either be a list or a dictionary, but it's no-longer JSON

Comment: You don't *need* to `read_json`, it's already been converted by `requests`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Gotcha. I was hoping to use .read_json() to have it format the JSON into a dataframe. What alternative would I use to put it into one?

Comment: If you're asking how you get a dataframe from a dictionary instead, or want to know how to get the body as a string in requests, I'd suggest you look at the relevant docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request does not return a Python dictionary -- the requests module's `.json()` method returns a dictionary. If your response is in json and you just want to use the string to load it in to pandas, use `response.text`.

Comment: When I removed the line defining `data`, I tried it again. I put in `type(response)`, it returned `requests.models.Response`. Unfortunately, pd.read_json() can't read that datatype either. It returns `Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'requests.models.Response'>`. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you use `response.text`? As in `pd.read_json(response.text)`?

Comment: I just did and it returned a dataframe! Thanks so much!